# How to present API response with redux and react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am new to front-end. I use react and redux-form after I subbmit form on backend don't know how to handle response and present it with react. My response is simply only one number.

````
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({
      type: CHANGE_ID_SUBMIT_DATA,
    });
    let reqBody = {
      firstname: changeId.firstName
      username: cnahgeId.userName,
    };

    return fetch(`${__REST_HOST__}/test/api/change/id`, {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(reqBody),
    }).then(
      response => dispatch(receiveData(response)),
      error => dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_ID_RESPONSE_ERR_DATA,
        error
      })
    );
  };
}

function receiveData(resp) {
  console.log(resp.text());

  return resp.text().then(response => dispatch({
    type: CHANGE_ID_RESPONSE_DATA,
    newId: response,
    receivedAt: moment(Date.now())
  }));
}```
````

Comment: what do you mean by "presenting it"?

Comment: How to show newId parameter into my react component. Because the response from api is only number.

Comment: How to implement action handler